# Why target="value" doesn't work with jQuery 'removeClass'?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, href, target, removeclass

I use removeClass javascript. But my links doesn't understand target="value" when I use that javascript. This is the exapmle http://jsfiddle.net/neoandrej/gGrFM/. How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Id should be unique. Class not.

Change in your HTML and in your JS:

```
<li class="vid" ...
```

In your case, jQuery find an element with id="vid", it removes its class and does not look further because it considers that this is the unique element.

With class, jQuery will keep going to find all the elements and remove their classes...

Comment: You're right, but it doesn't solve the problem: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/8yq6Q/)

Comment: @DidierG. that is because OP got `e.preventDefault()` on his click handler, which is a separate issue.

Comment: Yes it does. Take care of adding the class in both your html and your js.

Answer (score 0):

You have two elements with id `vid`. This is invalid and some browsers will return only first element matching `$("li#vid")` and others will return all of them, where as you need a specific one.
First change `vid` to be a class as opposed to id. Then use following to toggle your selected class

```
var clicked = this;
$("li.vid").each(function() { $(this).toggleClass("subtab-selected", this == clicked); });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/gGrFM/1/) of that. And here is optimized and cleaned up [version](http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/gGrFM/6/)